# How to select and limit the related_name connection in the Peewee ORM?

Tags: python, orm, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, peewee

I'm using Flask with the Peewee ORM in which I have defined two tables like so:

```
class Ticket(db.Model):
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    customer_uuid = CharField() # the customer's UUID gotten from App. More info comes from bunq API.
    ticket_type = ForeignKeyField(TicketType, related_name='tickets')
    active = BooleanField(default=True)

class Assign(db.Model):
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    ticket = ForeignKeyField(Ticket, related_name='assigned_to')
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='assigned_tickets')
```

In the Assign table, several users can be assigned to a ticket, but only the last one counts (i.e., if a new user gets assigned, the previous ones should be disregarded). So I select the active tickets using the following:

```
open_tickets = Ticket.select().where(Ticket.active == True)
```

I now want to use this loop in my template. With every iteration however, I also want to display the assigned user. But `open_ticket[0].assigned_to` obviously returns several assignments, and with it several users.

Would anybody know how I can get the latest assigned user for every ticket within a loop?

Comment: If a ticket can only be assigned to one user at a time, why not have the `user_id` as a FK in the ticket table?

Comment: @Doobeh - Because I want to be able to see to which it was assigned to before. In that way I can see what happened to the ticket and why for example, somebody got assigned to it, but changed it to a different user.

Comment: The nicest way for me to do it is to add some kind of active flag to assignment, a signal on assign creation (insert / update) to deactivate former assignments and then the query would be very simple (Assign.active == True)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Sqlite:

```
q = (Ticket
     .select(Ticket, Assign, User)
     .join(Assign)
     .join(User)
     .group_by(Ticket)
     .order_by(Ticket.id, Assign.id.desc()))

for ticket in q:
    print ticket.id, ticket.assign.user.username
```